# My wordpress site loads perfectly, but I cannot access the menus in the admin panel

Tags: errors

Initially, the admin panel home was not loading. But got that to work by adding a line of code in a php file. But it did not solve the main issue. I still can't access any of the menus and options. A circle spinning animation just keeps on going. I have tried renaming the themes and plugins folder to temporarily disable them, but it did not work.[image]
[image]

Comment: If you open the console, select that element, add `display: none;` or remove it, do you see the admin panel?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast no. Also, there are a couple errors that I am getting, which included 403 forbidden error, and mixed content error as well. I have attached a picture to the original post.

Comment: Is see that your hosting is hostgator, have you tried contacting them about this issue? They encounter many problems with wordpress daily and they are best equipped to help with those kind of problems

Comment: A clean, fresh WordPress installation would work. So something has changed or been added here to break this. You said you removed themes and plugins, that's a good step. Do it again, and also remove any .htaccess files present in your root directory and wp-admin directory.  403 and 500 errors are often caused by misconfigured or broken .htaccess files, respectively. Also, if you used a particular security plugin check for .user.ini in your root directory and delete that too.  Also that spinner is not a standard WordPress spinner afaik, so perhaps not all your plugins/themes are disabled.